# How to access row data in click event handler

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following section of jquery code - it works, and my table is populated with data, has titles etc. Now, As you can see, I have three buttons in every row under "actions" in this table... I need to be able to differentiate the rows for actions, though. The items in the JSON that I use for this, actually have a field named id, and it is populated, Is there a way I can add that field's value to each of the 'a' tags I have here? This would mean when I do the click event, I can get the id, and send the correct data to the REST API I am hitting... I just don't know how to populate it in here!

```
    $('#datatables').DataTable( {
        "data":resultA,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "description" },
            { "data": "id",
              "className": "text-right",
               "defaultContent":             

            '<td class="text-right">' +
                '<a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-info btn-icon like"><i class="material-icons">favorite</i></a>' +
                '<a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-warning btn-icon edit"><i class="material-icons">dvr</i></a>' +
                '<a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon remove"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>' +
            '</td>'
                                }
        ],
        fixedHeader: {
            header: true,
            footer: true
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

#### SOLUTION

You can retrieve row ID in your click event handler by getting `tr` element first and then retrieving data for that row using [`row().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) API method.

For example:

```js
// Handle click event on "Like" button
$('#datatables').on('click', 'a.like', function(){
   var api  = $('#datatables').DataTable();
   var data = api.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();

   console.log('ID is: ' + data['id']);
});
```

#### NOTES

You don't need to wrap your content in `<td></td>` in `defaultContent` option.